# How can I submit PDF into Microsoft .NET Web API

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a POST method in the the Microsoft .NET Web API. That post method processes PDF file into a Sharepoint Site. We did test this method in Postman, and this method works accordingly

However, we are trying to execute this method via the submit button on the PDF itself with the action URL specific for the Post method in the Web Api, the very same URL that properly works in the postman

When I try to execute that action/clicking the Submit button, I get a following error

[image]

Is there any specific strategy to execute the Web Api POST method directly through the PDF submit button

Thank you in advance

Here is my Web Api Post method

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("SubmitForm")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitForm()
        {

            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            HttpClient client = GetBinaryRequestClient();
            try
            {

                byte[] docAsBytes;
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    docAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(docAsBytes);
                MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                PdfStamper outStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,m);
                string formName = outStamper.AcroFields.GetField("FormSeqNo");

                string endpointUrl = string.Format(
                   "{0}{1}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{2}')/Files/Add(url='{3}', overwrite=true)",
                   this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SPSiteURL,
                   this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SmartFormsRelativeSiteURL,
                   this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SubmittedPDFsLibrary,
                   $"{formName}.pdf");

                ByteArrayContent imageBytes = new ByteArrayContent(docAsBytes);
                var result = await client.PostAsync(endpointUrl, imageBytes);

                return Ok(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, $"Error in method {ex.Message}");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Your Web API action expects form data but the PDF submit is sending direct `application/pdf` data. The Web API does not know how to handle it directly. hence the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there any way to specify form data in the PDF action settings. I only saw PDF and HTML options

Comment: Test it with HTML options and see what happens. <form> tag is part of HTML.

Comment: Just tried it, here is what I got ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.get_Item(int index)

Comment: Common checks to add include making sure the data received is not zero bytes long, making sure formName is not empty/blank, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that works for me. The .NET API method has to properly receive PDF based requests and write the responses back with the DFD type, NOT return it

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SubmitForm")]
public async Task SubmitForm()
{

    var file = Request.Body;
    HttpClient client = GetBinaryRequestClient();
    try
    {

        byte[] docAsBytes;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(ms);
            docAsBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(docAsBytes);
        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
        PdfStamper outStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader,m);
        string formName = outStamper.AcroFields.GetField("FormSeqNo");

        string endpointUrl = string.Format(
           "{0}{1}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{2}')/Files/Add(url='{3}', overwrite=true)",
           this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SPSiteURL,
           this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SmartFormsRelativeSiteURL,
           this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SubmittedPDFsLibrary,
           $"{formName}.pdf");

        ByteArrayContent imageBytes = new ByteArrayContent(docAsBytes);
        var result = await client.PostAsync(endpointUrl, imageBytes);
       Response.Redirect(this.apiService.AppSettings.SharePointSettings.SPSiteURL);

        //return Ok(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //return null;// StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, $"Error in method {ex.Message}");
        await ReturnFDFResponse("Error Occured " + ex.Message);
    }
}


private async Task ReturnFDFResponse(string status)
{
    string fdfmessage = "%FDF-1.2" + "\n" + "1 0 obj <<" + "\n" + "/FDF <<" +
        "\n" + "/Status (" + status + "!)" + "\n" + ">>" + "\n" +
        ">>" + "\n" + "endobj" + "\n" + "trailer" + "\n" + "<</Root 1 0 R>>" +
        "\n" + "%%EOF";

    HttpResponseMessage fdfresult = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fdfmessage));
    stream.Position = 0;
    fdfresult.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    fdfresult.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.fdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.fdf";
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(stream.ToArray());
}
```